# Why am I getting two different results while scanning in two same ways in HBase

Tags: java, hbase

I'm scanning HBase table through a java program in two ways.
One, from df-e0, and other from {df-df4, df4-df8, df8-dfc, dfc-e0}. These both results should be same, but I'm getting extra rows in the former way (df-e0). Also, I'm getting multiple versions(same keyrow, but different timestamps) in both ways.

My code of scanning hbase with start and end row parameters is given below :

```
int count = 0;
scan = new Scan(Bytes.toBytes(start), Bytes.toBytes(end));
scanner = keywordHBaseConnection.getKeywordMetaDataTable().getScanner(scan);
for (Result result = scanner.next(); result != null; result = scanner.next()) {
    count++;
}
```

I tried it with {start-end} = {df-e0}. And in other way, I tried it with {start-end} = {df-df4, df4-df8, df8-dfc, dfc-e0}, which are the subsets of previous one. Their outputs should be exactly same, but it's not. There are two problems in results - 
1. In former way, there are more rows in result.
2. There are duplicate rowkeys (multiple versions, I think) in both ways. (That shouldn't be the case bcz constructor scan() already sets maximum versions limit to one).

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing a specific version like:

```
scan.setMaxVersions(1);
```

which is still viable in version **1.2.x** or you can try with:

```
scan.readVersions(1);
```

for **2.x** client